# Passing an argument to a decorator inside a list accessing self vars?

Tags: python

How can I modify a `self` variable with a `decorator`?

Ex.

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self,a):
       self.a = a
       self.li = []

    def afunction(self):
       pass
```

I want to add the function object `afunction` to the list `self.li` so I can call it in a list. Ex. Have a list of functions defined by the class. How would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need a decorator. Functions are first-class objects in Python:

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self,a):
       self.a = a
       self.li = [self.afunction]

    def afunction(self):
       pass
```

Comment: It's worth noting this is also much better than using a decorator, as decorators don't act on instances, but the class itself, so `self.li` wouldn't exist when the decorator runs.

Comment: @Lattyware: decorators are passed the `self` argument too. Or at least, their *return value* will be treated as a method too. They don't act on classes, they act on functions. Unless you meant a class decorator...

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think he meant that function decorators on methods are run at the time the class definition is evaluated, not at the time each instance of the class is created. So, he's right, a decorator on `afunction` would not have a `self.li` to modify. (It's pretty hard to explain this in a way that's both technically correct and readable to novices…)

Comment: @MartijnPieters The decorator isn't passed `self`, the function the decorator deals with is. Important difference.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, decorators are executed at class build time; but the returned wrapper is used as a method. So during 'decorating' time there is no `self`, indeed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Which is what the question is asking about, as otherwise you'd have to run each function to generate the wanted list. (Which is not to say it isn't *possible* with decorators, in fact, [I've needed to do something like this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078877/how-to-get-a-reference-to-an-instance-method-from-a-decorator).)

Comment: @Lattyware: Right; I am a little tired (long day).

Comment: @MartijnPieters No worries, I've definitely been there before.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to mark certain functions of a class as a special type so that you can identify them later for some other purpose, you could use a decorator, or you could just use a naming convention.

```
def marked(function):

    function.marked = 1
    return function

class MarkAware(object):

    def run_marked(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for name in dir(self):
            meth = getattr(self, name)
            if hasattr(meth, 'marked'):
                meth(*args, **kwargs)

    def foo(self):
        pass

    @marked
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

Alternative:

```
class NameConvention(object):

     def run_batchable(self, *args, **kwargs):
         for name in dir(self):
             if name.startswith('batchable_'):
                 getattr(self, name)(*args, **kwargs)

     def foo(self):
         pass

     def batchable_bar(self):
         pass
```

Comment: +1, This is [the *mark and recapture* pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12078878/722121), and there are a few improvements one can make (linked example handles marks with more information, multiple marks, etc...).

Comment: Indeed, my comment was intended entirely as a bit of extra information, I think your answer distils it well for the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

As Lattyware explains in a comment to unutbu's answer, you can't directly do what you're asking, because any decorator on `afunction` will be run while the class itself is being created, not when each instance is created.

If all you really want is "a list of functions defined by the class", you don't need anything fancy at all for that. Just create that list in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a
    self.li = [f for f in dir(self) if inspect.ismethod(f)]
```

If you want a list of certain specific functions, the easiest way is the way `unutbu` suggests, which still doesn't require a decorator.

If you want the decorator just to mark "this method should go into `li`", see sr2222's answer.

None of these are what you asked for, but they are probably what you want. There are a few ways to actually use a decorator to add the function to `self.li`, but they're all pretty horrible, and you probably don't want them. For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
        self.li = []

        def mydecorator(f):
            self.li.append(f)
            return f

        @mydecorator
        def afunction(self):
            print('a')
        self.afunction = new.instancemethod(afunction, self, Foo)
```

Comment: @Lattyware: The explanation, or the code? I agree that the code is horrible, which is why I said so… But if the explanation is confusing, I can probably improve that if you give me specifics.

Comment: If you are going to go to these mindbending lengths, you might as well try a metaclass.

Comment: @sr2222: Well, that would be less horrible, but it would also mean you end up with a list in the class object, not the instance object, in which case you might as well go with the much simpler answer you posted. Maybe I'm just short on caffeine, but I can't think of any way to have a decorator affect instance variables directly except by either having the decorated functions defined inside `__init__`, having the decorator defined there and having it reach into the bound methods, or defining both there.

Comment: Modifying `self` in the decorator on the method itself, strictly speaking, I think no, but if you had a method tagging class that tracked things externally, you could decorate the class and then the functions, then have the class decorator part modify `self` seamlessly from the user perspective.  Of course then you are basically back to an overcomplicated mark and recapture, but it would technically be able to modify `self` once and only once for each instance...

Comment: @sr2222: Yeah, I think mark-and-decorate would definitely be better than doing this directly (which is why I both +1'd your answer and referred to it in mine); I'm just pointing out that it's not impossible to do. And if we're lucky, in doing so, I'm also showing why you don't want to do it. If it gave Lattyware a headache, I'm guessing it will turn off most novices even faster. :)