# Python, executing extra code at method definition

Tags: python, oop, decorator, metaclass

I am writing a python API/server to allow an external device (microcontroller) to remotely call methods of an object by sending a string with the name of the method. These methods would be stored in a dictionary. e.g. :

```
class Server:
    ...
    functions = {}
    def register(self, func):
        self.functions[func.__name__] = func
    def call(self, func_name, args):
        self.functions[func_name](*args)
    ...
```

I know that I could define functions externally to the class definition and register them manually, but I would really like that the registering step would be done automatically. Consider the following class:

```
class MyServer(Server):
    ...
    def add(self,a,b):
        print a+b
    def sub(self,a,b):
        print a-b
    ...
```

It would work by subclassing a server class and by defining methods to be called. How could I get the methods to be automatically registered in the functions dictionary?

One way that I thought it could be done is with a metaclass that look at a pattern in the methods name add if a match is found, add that methods to the functions dictionary. It seems overkill...

Would it be possible to decorate the methods to be registered? Can someone give me a hint to the simplest solution to this problem?

Comment: Your metaclass solution could also be done with a class decorator.  A decorator on the methods won't be able to store anything on the class because the class doesn't exist yet at the time a method decorator runs.

Comment: @BrenBarn There is [a solution to that issue](https://github.com/Lattyware/recap).

Comment: @Lattyware: Sure, I'm just saying you'll need some machinery besides a decorator on the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to construct a dictionary, just use [the `getattr()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
   def call(self, func_name, args):
        getattr(self, func_name)(*args)
```

Python actually uses a dictionary to access attributes on objects anyway (it's called `__dict__`, - but using `getattr()` is better than accessing it directly).

If you really want to construct that dict for some reason, then look at [the `inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/inspect.html):

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    self.functions = dict(inspect.getmembers(self, inspect.ismethod))
```

If you want to pick specific methods, you could use a decorator to do that, but as BrenBarn points out, the instance doesn't exist at the time the methods are decorated, so you need to use [the mark and recapture technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12078878/722121) to do what you want.

Comment: Indeed, this would be a better way to do it. But then, how would I print a list of methods defined in MyServer without storing them in a list and iterating over that list?

Comment: @Speccy If you want a list of all the methods, take a look at `inspect.getmembers()` - the second half of my answer.